# JPanel(null) not displaying JLabels

Tags: java, swing

I am adding JLabels from an Arraylist to a JPanel and they will only display if i set a layout on the panel but i want to set the location of the labels myself when i try `panel = new JPanel(null);` all labels are not displayed.

Frame:

```
public static void Frame(){
        panel = new JPanel(null);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("New");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.add(panel);
}
```

ArrayList iteration that adds labels to panel

```
private static void printArray() {
        for(int i = 0; i < food.size(); i++){
            component = new JLabel(new Food(food.get(i).getColor(), 
            food.get(i).getIconHeight(), food.get(i).getIconWidth(), 
            food.get(i).getLocationX(), food.get(i).getLocationY()));
            panel.add(component);
            component.setLocation(food.get(i).getLocationX(), 
            food.get(i).getLocationY());
        }
}
```

I can see from Debug it is definitely getting the location information, so why is it not putting it in this location.

[image]

Comment: Guess what job the "layout manager" does? Guess what happens when you set it to `null`

Comment: *"I am adding JLabels from an Arraylist to a JPanel and they will only display if i set a layout*" - That's correct,  *"but i want to set the location of the labels myself"* - Well, first, I'd be asking why? What are you trying to do that the available layout managers can't do?

Comment: @MadProgrammer hey mate im following this code http://www.camick.com/java/source/MotionWithKeyListener.java and it seems as though he does the same thing and it works fine is his code. The reason to set layout as null is so i can update the position of the label so i can "move" it around with keyboard input and in this doc they also suggest to set it to null https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

P.s. love your work on SO.

Comment: So the first thing you need to understand is what work the layout manager does, it's responsible for deciding the size and location of the components, since you've decided to remove it, you will now become responsible for doing so, components have a default size of `0x0` and a default location of `0x0`. As good as Camick's work is, I'd also recommend using the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`

Comment: Maybe add `component.setVisible(true)` in your iteration? I think this may be originally done by a layout manager, but since you have none, you may have to do it yourself.

Comment: @glee8e Components are visible by default - Window based close are the exception (including `JInternalFrame`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason to set layout as null is so i can update the position of the label so i can "move" it around with keyboard input

The first thing you need to do is understand what job the layout manager actually does, because if you're going to remove it, you're going to need to take over it's work.

Layout managers are responsible for determining both the size and position of the components. They do this through a variety of means, but can make use of the `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize` methods of the components.

So this would suggest you need to make your own determinations about these values, for example...

```
component = new JLabel(new Food(food.get(i).getColor(), 
        food.get(i).getIconHeight(), food.get(i).getIconWidth(), 
        food.get(i).getLocationX(), food.get(i).getLocationY()));
component.setSize(component.getPreferredSize());
component.setLocation(food.get(i).getLocationX(), food.get(i).getLocationY());
```

I'd also recommend using the [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`, it doesn't suffer from the same focus related issues